# separar string en cada mayuscula o numero

Tags: php, string

necesito separar un string con "_" cada vez que encuentra una mayuscula y transformarla a minusculas. Esto para separar cada palabra  del nombre de clase, por ejemplo si tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class UserNote{
}
```

el nombre de esa clase quedaría como:
user_notes

Hice éste metodo pero solo funciona cuando la clase tiene 1 palabra:

```
public function parseClassName(){
    $className = strtolower(get_class($this));
    return $className . 's';
}
```

**SOLUCIONADO:**

Gracias chicos, he probado con ambas respuestas y ambas funcionan correctamente.
Mi método ha quedado así para cada una de las respuestas.

```
public function parseClassName(){
    $className = preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', ucwords(get_class($this)));
    $className = mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)(?=[A-Z])/u', '$1_', $className));
    return $className . 's';
}
```

El otro método:

```
public function parseClassName(){

    $className = preg_replace('/(?<=\w)(\p{Lu})/u', '_$1', get_class($this));
    $className = mb_strtolower($className);
    return $className . 's';
}
```

Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Con esa función efectivamente sólo estás llevando a minúsculas las mayúsculas, pero te falta lo de separar las palabras. Podrías investigar los códigos ASCII de las letras mayúsculas, hacer un ciclo donde las busques, y cada vez que la encuentres, le antepones al texto el guión bajo...

Comment: ¿En **cada** mayúscula? ¿`CodigoHTMLEjemplo` debería convertirse en `codigo_h_t_m_l_ejemplo` o en `codigo_html_ejemplo`?

Comment: si, en cada mayúscula, en gran parte de los casos funciona, en caso de excepciones como esa indico el atributo manualmente, como en laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el underscore puedes utilizar [`preg_replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php), de acuerdo a la documentación:

> **replacement** puede contener referencias de la forma \\n o $n, siendo preferida la última forma. Cada referencia de este tipo será sustituida por el texto capturado por el n-simo patrón entre paréntesis.

Así que podemos utilizar `'_$1'` como el valor de `replacement`, y la expresión regular `/(?<=\w)(\p{Lu})/u`, de esta forma

```
echo mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=\w)(\p{Lu})/u', '_$1', 'UserNote'));
```

Que imprimirá esto: `user_note`

Para ponerlo como plural debes considerar muchas cosas, como por ejemplo palabras irregulares, o el idioma. Creo que para tu ejemplo bastaría con agregarle `s` al final que sirve para la mayoría de los casos, de esta forma:

```
$word = 'UserNote';
$underscore = mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=\w)(\p{Lu})/u', '_$1', $word));
$plural = $underscore . 's';

echo $plural;
```

Imprimirá: `user_notes`.

---

Lo que hace la expresión regular es asegurarse que existe una palabra antes para no poner un `_` al inicio y atrapa todo lo que sea letra mayúscula

Comment: ¿Por qué precedido por `\w`? No te olvides de letras con diacríticos por ejemplo... Además, si citaste al manual y dice que se prefiere la última forma, por qué usás la primera?

Comment: El `\w` es para que no agregue un `_` al inicio por si la palabra empieza con una mayuscula. Y tienes razón modifiqué mi respuesta para que acepte todas las letras mayúsculas

Comment: Entendí eso. Me refiero a algo como `AcáFalla`.. Y no es necesaria la doble barra en `\\w`

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, corregido. Y como siempre, gracias :)

Comment: Gracias, ésto funciona correctamente también, la marcaré como correcta ya que da más información  sobre el método necesario.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a colaborar con el código que utiliza Laravel para convertir a `snake_case` que es como normalmente se llama a este estilo, lo adapto levemente para que funcione sin las dependencias internas del framework:

```
public function snake($value, $delimiter = '_')
{
    if (! ctype_lower($value)) {
        $value = preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', ucwords($value));
        $value = mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/(.)(?=[A-Z])/u', '$1'.$delimiter, $value));
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Aquí está la fuente completa de dicho helper: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L439

Comment: Gracias, precisamente buscaba convertirlo tal cual como hace laravel, lo he probado y funciona correctamente. La verdad ambas respuestas funcionan correctamente, pero marcaré la de KacosPro ya que contiene más información sobre el uso de la función necesaria. Saludos, y gracias nuevamente, editaré la publicación y dejaré ambas soluciones.